# Bitmap image saving with size 0kb

Tags: android, bitmap, storage, android-custom-view

I tried several codes to save my custom view into a .jpg format. I am converting the view to a bitmap and then saving it as shown below. But at every attempt the saved image size is always 0 Kb  and the file does not contain anything. I have already put the following permission.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

here is one of the codes I have used;

```
drawView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
drawView.buildDrawingCache();
Bitmap b = drawView.getDrawingCache();
 private void SaveImage(Bitmap finalBitmap) {

      String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
      File myDir = new File(root + "/saved_images");    
      myDir.mkdirs();
      String fname = "Image.jpg";
      File file = new File (myDir, fname);
      if (file.exists ()) file.delete (); 
        try {
           FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
           finalBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);
           out.flush();
           out.close();

     } catch (Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
     }
 }
```

I also wanted to precise that the main idea of this code is not from me.

the whole complete code;
     public class DrawPad extends View {

```
//drawing path
    private Path drawPath;
    //drawing and canvas paint
    private Paint drawPaint, canvasPaint;
    //initial color
    private int paintColor =0xff000000;
    //canvas
    private Canvas drawCanvas;
    //canvas bitmap
    private Bitmap canvasBitmap;

    //erase flag
    private boolean erase=false;

    public DrawPad(Context context, AttributeSet attrs){
        super(context, attrs);
        setupDrawing();


    }
    public Paint getPaint(){
        return drawPaint;
    }
    //setup drawing
    private void setupDrawing(){

        //prepare for drawing and setup paint stroke properties

        drawPath = new Path();
        drawPaint = new Paint();
        drawPaint.setColor(paintColor);
        drawPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        drawPaint.setStrokeWidth(1.0f);
        drawPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        drawPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
        drawPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
        canvasPaint = new Paint(Paint.DITHER_FLAG);

    }
    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
        canvasBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        drawCanvas = new Canvas(canvasBitmap);
    }

    //draw the view - will be called after touch event
    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawBitmap(canvasBitmap, 0, 0, canvasPaint);
        canvas.drawPath(drawPath, drawPaint);
    }

    //register user touches as drawing action
    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        float touchX = event.getX();
        float touchY = event.getY();
        //respond to down, move and up events
        switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            drawPath.moveTo(touchX, touchY);
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            drawPath.lineTo(touchX, touchY);
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            drawPath.lineTo(touchX, touchY);
            drawCanvas.drawPath(drawPath, drawPaint);
            drawPath.reset();
            break;
        default:
            return false;
        }
        //redraw
        invalidate();
        return true;

    }

    //update color
    public void setColor(String newColor){
        invalidate();
        paintColor = Color.parseColor(newColor);
        drawPaint.setColor(paintColor);
    }

    //set erase true or false
    public void setErase(boolean isErase){
        erase=isErase;

        if(erase){ 
            drawPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR));
            drawPaint.setStrokeWidth(15.0f);
        }
        else {
            drawPaint.setStrokeWidth(1.0f);
            drawPaint.setXfermode(null);
        }
    }

    //start new drawing
    public void startNew(){
        drawCanvas.drawColor(0, PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR);
        drawPaint.setStrokeWidth(1.0f);
        invalidate();
    }
    public void SaveImage(Bitmap finalBitmap,String spin) {
        if(finalBitmap == null) {
            Toast unsavedToast = Toast.makeText(getContext(), 
                    "Oops! Page could not be saved.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            unsavedToast.show();
            }

          this.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
          this.buildDrawingCache();
          finalBitmap=this.getDrawingCache();
          String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
          File myDir = new File(root + "/answers");    
          myDir.mkdirs();
          String fname = spin+".jpg";
          File file = new File (myDir, fname);
          if (file.exists ()) file.delete (); 
            try {
               FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
              if ( finalBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out)==true){
               out.flush();
               out.close();
              }
              if(finalBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out)==false){
                Toast fToast = Toast.makeText(getContext(), 
                        "compression failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                fToast.show();
              }

         } catch (Exception e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: The write permission is working, otherwise you wouldn't be able to create a file at all. The `finalBitmap` is fishy. Is there really something in it? As a sanity check you could write a string to the file, like "hello".

Comment: i'm able to write a string to the file of course i've change extension to txt.

Comment: So writing to your storage is fine, something's wrong with `finalBitmap` then, see my answer. Btw the filename extension doesn't matter at all.

Answer (score 1):

Check the returned value of `finalBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);`

The [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#compress%28android.graphics.Bitmap.CompressFormat,%20int,%20java.io.OutputStream%29) says the method returns true if successfully compressed to the specified stream. I bet it returns false for you.

Check what is in the bitmap you're trying to compress. It seems it's empty, or something's wrong with it. Find where the Bitmap is created and check if every step is successful or not. Just like `finalBitmap.compress` returns true/false on success/failure, check every operation on the Bitmap from the point it was created, because it looks like something went wrong somewhere.

If you still cannot figure out, then add to your post all the code that manipulates `finalBitmap` before it enters your `SaveImage` method. (And btw methods in Java should start with lowercase letter, for example `saveImage`.)

Comment: You were good, the compression returns false. i will edit my question to add  the complete code for the drawing view. I normally call the saved function from a main activity.

Comment: @Katy the code you pasted doesn't include the call to `SaveImage`, that's the most important piece, to see where `finalBitmap` comes from...

Comment: here is the code in the onClickListener;

    drawview.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    drawview.buildDrawingCache();
    Bitmap b = dp.getDrawingCache();
    drawview.SaveImage(b,spinner1.getSelectedItem().toString());

Comment: @Katy In `SaveImage` we found that the received `Bitmap` appears to be empty. Now we know it comes from `dp.getDrawingCache()`, but what is `dp` and where *that* comes from? You need to trace your steps backwards one by one like that.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your bitmap equals to null value. Could you check your bitmap?

Comment: how could i check if its null?

Comment: On SaveImage method first line set this code; if(finalBitmap == null) throw new NullPointerException();

Comment: I've tried and there no null exception in logcat, I have even use toast to check if it was null but it wasnt